# not able to mine contract. geth shuts down automatically

Tags: go-ethereum, ethminer

i'm using the known crowdfunding and token contracts from ethereum.org only slightly modified

```
contract Token{
    function Token(tokenName,tokenValue,totalSupply){
      //assign these parameter values to contract variable by the same name; 
    } 
    function transfer(address to,uint amount){
       //perform transfer operation
    }
  }
contract crowdfunding{
   Token token;
    function crowdfunding(address tokenAddr){
    token = Token(tokenAddr)
    }
    function contribute(){
    token.transfer(msg.sender,amount);
    // transfer function of Token contract is called
    }
}
```

the 2 contracts deploy just fine. when i want to execute contribute function the following thing happens

i get this error everytime i try to mine :

```
panic: ethash_full_new IO or memory error.
goroutine 128 [running]:
panic(0xcfae80, 0xc083c00670)
    C:/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:481 +0x3f4
github.com/ethereum/ethash.(*dag).generate.func1()
    D:/builds/geth_win32/build-go-win-master/build/Godeps/_workspace/src/git
```

and so on

what should i do?

i was getting this error therefore i deleted the chaindata and started afresh and yet the error persists.

Comment: How much RAM does your computer or VM have?

Answer (score 1):

If you have managed to mine before and this is occurring the first time check for memory intensive processes (use task manager/[sysinternal](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545021.aspx) suite). I had a similar issue on a machine running firefox with a large number of open tabs.

Comment: i have plenty memory.this error comes when i try to execute a particular function only.could it be a result of datatype difference in the code ?

Comment: Can you please update your question with the function. It may be that you are extending an array with too many elements or are using a recursive call that has no or a buggy stopping condition.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue of memory panic

I solved it by

1) Checking for the **geth bit (32/64 )** I had system of 64bit and ran geth of 32bit and hence faced this issue.

2) Checking for the **Storage size** I had a Azure VM whose internal memory/RAM size was just 3.5GB and which is not sufficient for DAG generated and stored.